# What's the difference between __dict__ and getattr?

Tags: python, reflection

I'm trying to iterate all the variables of the class `A` which contains some coroutine methods in the module `a.py`. I use two ways to achieve my purpose, but the results are different:

Method 1: use `getattr()`

```
a = __import__('a')
print('===========getattr()=============')
func_sync = getattr(a, 'func_sync')
func_async = getattr(a, 'func_async')
print(func_sync)  # <function func_sync at 0x7f827b98f510>
print(func_async)  # <function func_async at 0x7f8279cd01e0>
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func_async))  # True
# getattr class
A = getattr(a, 'A')
print(A)  # <class 'a.A'>
method_aa = getattr(A, 'aa')
method_bb = getattr(A, 'bb')
method_cc = getattr(A, 'cc')
print(method_aa)  # <bound method A.aa of <class 'a.A'>>  <----notice this
print(method_bb)  # <function A.bb at 0x7f8279cd00d0>
print(method_cc)  # <function A.cc at 0x7f8279cd0158>
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method_aa))  # True  <---- meet my expectations
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method_bb))  # True
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method_cc))  # False
```

It seems that all the results meet my expectations. But when I use `__dict__`, problem occurs

```
print('=========== __dict__ =============')
A = a.__dict__['A']
func_sync = a.__dict__['func_sync']
func_async = a.__dict__['func_async']
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func_async))  # True
print(A)  # <class 'a.A'>
method_aa = A.__dict__['aa']
method_bb = A.__dict__['bb']
method_cc = A.__dict__['cc']
print(method_aa)  # <classmethod object at 0x7f827a21c908>  <---- different from before
print(method_bb)  # <function A.bb at 0x7f8279cd00d0>
print(method_cc)  # <function A.cc at 0x7f8279cd0158>
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method_aa))  # False <----- I think it should be True
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method_bb))  # True
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method_cc))  # False
```

Can someone explain for me?

This is `a.py`

```
class A:

    @classmethod
    async def aa(cls):
        return 123

    async def bb(self):
        return 456

    def cc(self):
        return 789


def func_sync():
    return 'sync'


async def func_async():
    return 'async'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classmethod` decorator works by returning an object that implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html).

When you access such object through the class using attribute access or `getattr`, the protocol is put into action and you get the desired result, a method bound to the specified class:

```
method_aa = getattr(A, 'aa')
# bound method - calling method_aa() automatically supplies `A` to the function
```

If you access it through the class's `__dict__` instead, you get the raw `classmethod` *object* instead, which can be used to obtain a method bound to class, but is itself not one.

```
method_aa_desc = A.__dict__['aa']
# a descriptor, which we cannot call, but which we can _bind_ to AA
method_aa = method_aa_desc.__get__(None, A)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have read the article you give and It exactly what I want.